# How can I tell if numpy is using threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

I wan't to know if numpy is using threads over the available cores on my system. I know MATLAB does this under the hood. But is there any sure fire way I can find out if numpy is running threaded. My understanding is that it can, as Pythons GIL no longer applies. Is there anyway I can interrogate numpy either statically or at run-time to find whats going on?

Comment: You can use `top` on a Linux system, and look how much CPU it uses. If it is more than 100%, then it uses two or more cores.

Comment: Try some computation intensive call, like huge SVD. Normally `numpy` will use many threads to compute.

Comment: @Alex As far as i know, ubuntu ships multithreaded/openmp-based BLAS for years now. Even more for anaconda's MKL. So for many users: multithreading is on by default.

Comment: @sascha interesting - thanks! Here's [a relevant link](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/ParallelProgramming) to some old Scipy docs.